# Titanium - lifecycle of a ti.app.proper

Tags: android, ios, titanium

Does anybody know what the lufecyycle of a ti.app.property is in titanium?

I am wantng to do some stuff on application startup *only*, and was wanting to hold if the thing in question had occurred or not in a ti.app.property field. the problem is, i am unsure if this field, once set, will persist across the "home" button or "back" button being pressed.

So is there some place at suggests when a ti.app.property field is instantiated/destroyed etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It persists till the app is deleted from your phone or you programmatically reset / delete it.

[Exact quote from the documentation:](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties)

> The App Properties module is used for storing application-related data in property/value pairs that persist beyond application sessions and device power cycles.

Comment: sooooo... does that mean that each time a global value is set, there should be an accompanying check to see if it is null first?

Comment: you can simply check whether it exists or not before (re)setting it: Ti.App.Properties.hasProperty('myProp')